# Why Python't any() function doesn't work for list of character checking?

Tags: python, function, boolean

When I use int

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 1, 2]

print(all(a) in b)
```

the result is `True`.

But, when I use characters

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = ["c", "b", "a"]

print(all(a) in b)
```

the result is `False`

Why in this case result is `False`?

Comment: `all(a) in b` is `all([1, 2, 3]) in b` which is `True in b` which is `1 in b` which is`True`.

Comment: FWIW, the correct way to use `all` here would be `all(i in b for i in a)`, though that's very inefficient.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked posts, I'm not sure why this is closed.

Answer (score 2):

`all(a)` in both cases returns `True`, so you are basically running

```
print(True in [3, 1, 2])
```

and

```
print(True in ["c", "b", "a"])
```

`True == 1` returns `True` in python, so since there is the value `1` inside the integer `b` list, `True in b` returns `True` for the integer `b` list.

And because `True` woundn't equal to any string, `True in b` returns `False` for the string `b` list